# How do I set up a local standalone NTP server using NTPsec?

Tags: ntp

Debian deprecated the old ntpd package anymore and is instead now using https://ntpsec.org/

I was using the old ntpd to provide a local timeserver in a docker container. This docker container is not connected to the internet nor to any other timeservers. It should act as a timeserver for local devices in it's network.

When I used the now deprecated ntpd for this, I had to set `fudge 127.127.1.1 stratum 8` to set the stratum to 8. Because the server could not get it's time from another server, it's stratum was 0. When the client tried to synchronize the time it got an answer but did not accept it.

Now with ntpsec this does not seem to work anymore. I do

```
root@e2d0c2489be9:/# tcpdump  -n -c 2 -v
```

on the ntp server.
When I restart sytemd-timesyncd on the client using

```
systemctl restart systemd-timesyncd
```

I get this output from tcpdump on the server

```
tcpdump: listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), snapshot length 262144 bytes
14:18:52.564299 IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 55918, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    192.168.1.81.33587 > 192.168.1.193.123: NTPv4, Client, length 48
        Leap indicator:  (0), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 0 (1s), precision 0
        Root Delay: 0.000000, Root dispersion: 0.000000, Reference-ID: (unspec)
          Reference Timestamp:  0.000000000
          Originator Timestamp: 0.000000000
          Receive Timestamp:    0.000000000
          Transmit Timestamp:   3907837176.154516687 (2023-11-01T14:19:36Z)
            Originator - Receive Timestamp:  0.000000000
            Originator - Transmit Timestamp: 3907837176.154516687 (2023-11-01T14:19:36Z)
14:18:52.564480 IP (tos 0xb8, ttl 64, id 43066, offset 0, flags [DF], proto UDP (17), length 76)
    192.168.1.193.123 > 192.168.1.81.33587: NTPv4, Server, length 48
        Leap indicator: clock unsynchronized (192), Stratum 0 (unspecified), poll 0 (1s), precision -23
        Root Delay: 0.000000, Root dispersion: 0.000137, Reference-ID: (unspec)
          Reference Timestamp:  0.000000000
          Originator Timestamp: 3907837176.154516687 (2023-11-01T14:19:36Z)
          Receive Timestamp:    3907837132.564299408 (2023-11-01T14:18:52Z)
          Transmit Timestamp:   3907837132.564463209 (2023-11-01T14:18:52Z)
            Originator - Receive Timestamp:  -43.590217279
            Originator - Transmit Timestamp: -43.590053478
```

Although the docs of ntpsec mention that old way configuration should still work, apparently it does not. (https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/ntpsec.html#configuration)

I found this instead: https://docs.ntpsec.org/latest/driver_local.html
But putting

```
refclock local stratum 8
```

into the file `/etc/ntpsec/ntp.conf` does not work either. I get the some output of tcpdump like above.

Expected outcome:
Setting `refclock local stratum 8` in ntp.conf sets the stratum to 8